# Youtube's connection status bottom bar

Tags: android, statusbar, android-snackbar

In my app I wanted to implement a status bar at the bottom of the main activity, but I want it the same way YouTube app developers done it. In YouTube app, when wifi or internet connex is off a slim status bar at the bottom appears.**I can only think of a custom snackbar.**

What you guys think?

Comment: It is possible with snackbar. Please also note that don't ask question which are based on opinion.. You could show what you have tried so far, if there is any error you can get help

Comment: Sorry. Next time I will. Thank you. Your answer is appreciated.